# Homework: How do i calculate the time complexity of this function?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
void func(int n){
    int i=1, k=n;
    while (i<=k){
        k=k/2;
        i = i*2;
    }
}
```

How do i calculate the time complexity of this function? I understand that the assignment of i=1, k=n takes two basic steps and to divide the value of k and multiply the value of i takes two basic steps as well, but because the values of i and k are increasing and decreasing exponentially, will the time complexity be O(log base 4 N) or O(log base 2 sqrt(N))?

Comment: I think it s O(log2(n)/2). If you ignore the `k=k/2` then it is log2(n) since `i` is essentially `2^m` where m is the number of iteration going from 0.

Comment: You have to think about how many steps does it have to make. You can safely ignore the constant time it takes to assign the variables. The you are starting with i = 1 and k = n , and in each cycle you are doubling i and making k half, essentialy you are finding x where functions n/(2^x) and 1 * (2^x) "meet in the middle". Take this with a grain of salt, but i feel like it should be about O(log4(n)) (I suggest you write a few iterations of it on a paper)

Comment: Or in other words, it's O(log n), since both of the comments above are that written in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is O(log √n), in the comments @Eraklon says it's O((log<sub>2</sub> n)/2), and @matri70boss says it's O(log<sub>4</sub> n). All three of you are correct, but the answer in its simplest form is O(log n).

- log √n = log n<sup>0.5</sup> = 0.5 log n, and we discard the constant factor 0.5 when we write in big O notation.
- (log<sub>2</sub> n)/2 = (log n)/(2 log 2) by the [change of base identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base), and 1/(2 log 2) is another constant factor we can discard.
- Likewise, log<sub>4</sub> n = (log n)/(log 4), and we can discard the constant factor 1/(log 4).